# How to find the max character using a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-like, sql-server-2016

This should be relatively easy.  I look at claims data for a living.  I have the following hypothetical ClaimID:  17060C048388A3

A little bit about this, is the A in the 14th character space stands for 'Adjustment' with the following number being the number of time is has been adjusted.  So for instance, this specific claim has been adjusted 3 times.
Unfortunately ClaimID 17060C048388A1, 17060C048388A2, and 17060C048388A3 (all three adjustments show).  How do I only select the highest adjustment to avoid duplication when counting these claims.  Not all claims are adjusted so they don't all have A's and aren't all 15 characters.

So I think I need to start a case statement as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000 *,
    CASE WHEN CLAIMID LIKE '%A%' THEN ??????
```

Any suggestions on grabbing the next highest digit after the 'A' in the ClaimID, if there is an 'A' in the ClaimID.  So if the claim had 8 adjustments, I only want to see the one that ends in A8.

Thanks in advance guys,
Anon

Comment: which dbms (mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgres) you are using? please tag your question.

Comment: Please stop vandalizing posts on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I looked on your question again and created the following solution:

```
SELECT base, MAX(adjustment) AS max_adjustment, base + IIF(MAX(adjustment) > 0, 'A', '') + MAX(adjustment) max_adjusted_claim
FROM (
  SELECT 
    IIF(PATINDEX('%A%', ClaimID) = 0, ClaimID, LEFT(ClaimID, PATINDEX('%A%', ClaimID)-1)) AS base, 
    REPLACE(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(ClaimID), PATINDEX('%A%', REVERSE(ClaimID)))), 'A', '') AS adjustment
  FROM table_name
)t GROUP BY base
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5f40ea72adf4fb708a2233f4619f19c9)

Comment: @GregoryBrauninger - I updated my solution should work for many possibilties now (have a look at the demo with some test values).

Answer (score 0):

this will work even simpler;

```
select * from Table1 where
regexp_like("column1",substr("column1",1,instr("column1",'A'))||
            (select max(substr("column1",-1)) from Table1) );`
```

check this:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb16f/7

Answer (score 0):

With a CTE:

```
with cte as(
  select
    claimid,
    case 
      when claimid like '%A%' then left(claimid, charindex('A', claimid) - 1) 
      else claimid
    end claim,
    case 
      when claimid like '%A%' then cast(right(claimid, len(claimid) - charindex('A', claimid)) as int)
      else 0
    end adjustment
  from tablename
)
select distinct top 10000 t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select 
    claim + 
    case max(adjustment) 
      when 0 then ''
      else 'A' + cast(max(adjustment) as varchar(10))
    end claimid 
  from cte
  group by claim
) g on g.claimid = t.claimid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b53e76bee5d1c53002d83f30f6d1f22a).
For this sample data:

```
> claimid        | value
> :------------- | :----
> 17060C048388A1 | a    
> 17060C048388A2 | b    
> 17060C04838811 | c    
> 17060C04838866 | d    
> 17060C04838855 | e    
> 17060C048388A3 | f    
> 17060C04838899 | g
```

the results are:

```
> claimid        | value
> :------------- | :----
> 17060C04838811 | c    
> 17060C04838866 | d    
> 17060C04838855 | e    
> 17060C048388A3 | f    
> 17060C04838899 | g
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (assuming I don't notice any bugs).  I took examples from all the comments and put this together so thank you everyone that replied.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(CLAIMID, 1,13) + MAX(RIGHT(CLAIMID, 2)) AS 
MAX_CLAIM_ADJUSTMENT
FROM LA_TEMP.DBO.ITEM19
WHERE (SUBSTRING(CLAIMID, 14, 1) = 'A'
OR SUBSTRING(CLAIMID, 13, 1) = 'A')
GROUP BY left(CLAIMID, 13)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(CLAIMID, 1,14) + MAX(RIGHT(CLAIMID, 1)) AS 
MAX_CLAIM_ADJUSTMENT
FROM LA_TEMP.DBO.ITEM19
WHERE (SUBSTRING(CLAIMID, 15, 1) = 'A'
OR SUBSTRING(CLAIMID, 14, 1) = 'A')
GROUP BY left(CLAIMID, 14)
ORDER BY MAX_CLAIM_ADJUSTMENT
```

I noticed the A can either be the 13th or 14th character.

Comment: Your code fails when the number after A is longer than 1 digit because you get that number as a string, so if there exists A10 you will get A9 as max.